# How is equality determined for Python frozenset instances?

Tags: python, set, frozenset

How is the code below possible?

```
>>> frozenset(('a_')) == frozenset(['a_'])
False
>>> frozenset(('a')) == frozenset(['a'])
True
```

My understanding is that so long as each each element of the iterable is hashable, a frozen set will be instantiated with each element being an element of the given iterable. I expect that both expressions above should return `True`.

Comment: `('a_')` isn't a tuple. `('a_')` is just `'a_'`.

Comment: I see, so since a string is an iterable, `frozenset` will construct a set from each character of `a_`, which means `frozenset(['a', '_']) == frozenset(('a_'))` evaluates to `True`.